# Batch File to automatically abort shutdown

Tags: batch-file, time, shutdown, abort, confirmation

My computer shuts down every night starting at 9:59 and continuing until 11:59. I do not know why. I'm wondering if a .bat file could be written to automatically abort the shutdowns, or at least require confirmation?

Comment: which system, widonws? check if there are any scheduled job set in control panel?

Comment: Definitely sounds like there's something in the Task Scheduler that's triggering the shutdowns. You can use `shutdown /a` to abort the shutdowns, but until you find the root cause of the issue, this is just a stopgap solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some unwanted software installed in your system. Check in the startup directory, remove any unwanted exe or batch files.

Check the scheduled task in windows using below command in older windows

```
at
```

After windows 7

```
schtasks.exe
```

Delete the unwanted tasks. Scan your system using **Windows Defender**

Below is the command used to abort the shutdown.

```
shutdown -a
```